# Understanding Google Benchmark Result

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I am doing a benchmark of the performance of various Hash table implementations. The code reads integers from an in-memory vector and writes them to the hash table.

Here's my code for the benchmark base class

```
class ConcurrentBenchmark : public benchmark::Fixture {
protected:

    vector<int32_t> values;

public:

    ConcurrentBenchmark() {
        srand(time(NULL));

        int total = 1000000;

        for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
            values.push_back(rand() % 1000);
        }
    }

    virtual ~ConcurrentBenchmark() {}
};

BENCHMARK_F(ConcurrentBenchmark, Int32) {...}

BENCHMARK_F(ConcurrentBenchmark, Int64) {...}

BENCHMARK_F(ConcurrentBenchmark, StlInt32) {...}

BENCHMARK_F(ConcurrentBenchmark, StlInt64) {...}
```

Here's the result.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                             Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ConcurrentBenchmark/Int32       4612777 ns      1081463 ns          645
ConcurrentBenchmark/Int64       6192677 ns      2234226 ns          300
ConcurrentBenchmark/StlInt32    8101856 ns      8101747 ns           86
ConcurrentBenchmark/StlInt64    7958493 ns      7958290 ns           88
```

My question is: it seems like the CPU time is aligned with Iterations, e.g., CPU * Iterations is a constant. But what does the "Time" column tells us? Does this time include the initialization, e.g., filling the in-memory buffers?